# Run time error "Please make sure you're using the same version of Mongoose everywhere with `npm list mongoose`."

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

As part of my feature, I am making changes to a dependent repository as well. So I am 'requiring' the local copy of the dependent repository. I am getting error while running my project file

`` .....throw new TypeError('Schema for array path `' + path + ^ TypeError: Schema for array path `key_meta` is from a different copy of the Mongoose module. Please make sure you're using the  same version of Mongoose everywhere with `npm list mongoose`. ``

When I run `npm list mongoose` I could see that all the projects are using same mongoose version `mongoose@5.13.14  deduped`.

NOTE: I have the latest copy of both the repositories